# MIRTH channels are gone

Tags: mirth

After editing one of my channels to connect through database server, I ran into some permissions error. Aside from that, now I can't edit my channels anymore because all the channels disappeared, only the channel groups are left and they have the status N/A. However, my deployed channels are still running fine as shown in the dashboard tab. Do I have to fix the permission issue first and only then will I be able to see my channels in the channels tab again?

[channel page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uAwD.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace? Does this error always show up when you open the channels tab? What was the permission error when connecting to the database server?